# Maximum number of transitive triples in 3-partite diconnected tournament

Tags: graph-theory

> Show that if $T$ is strongly connected 3-partite tournament with partite sets $V_0,V_1,V_2$ then the maximum number of transitive triples is $|V_0||V_1||V_2|-1$, unless $|V_0|=|V_1|=|V_2|=2$, in which case $T$ has at most $|V_0||V_1||V_2|-2$ transitive triples.

My attempt was to prove that it contains at least one 3-cycle using this theorem: Let $T$ be a k-partite tournament, $k\geq 3$, contains a directed 3-cycle iff there exist a directed cycle in $T$ that contains vertices from at least three partite sets.

Since $T$ is strongly connected I can find a path between any two vertices, but if I take one vertex in each of the trhee components, I don't know if the resulting walk is indeed a cycle (ie it does not have repeated vertices)